# Visual Basic SSRS - Deploy report with predefined data source credentials

Tags: vb.net, vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am uploading programmatically a report on the server through the use of `rs.exe` and a visual basic file. When the user views the report, the server asks for credentials to log in to the Data Source.

[image: Credentials prompt]

Now, when I upload a report through Visual Studio, there is an option to use specific credentials that you can pre-set so the user is not prompted. I also notice that there is a setting in the report where you can define credentials.

[image: Credentials settings]

My question is, how do I enable the use of specific data source credentials on uploading the report with Visual Basic so the user is not prompted for the data source credentials?

My VB code:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim definition As [Byte]() = Nothing
        Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
        Dim stream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(RDL_LOCATION)

        definition = New [Byte](stream.Length) {}
        stream.Read(definition, 0, CInt(stream.Length))
        warnings = rs.CreateReport(REPORT_NAME, "/" + REPORT_FOLDER, True, definition, Nothing)
        If Not (warnings Is Nothing) Then
            Dim warning As Warning
            For Each warning In warnings
                Console.WriteLine(warning.Message)
            Next warning
        Else
            AddPolicies("/" + REPORT_FOLDER + "/" + REPORT_NAME, "False")
            Console.WriteLine("Report: {0} PUBLISHED!", REPORT_NAME)
        End If
    Catch e As IOException
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
        Console.Read()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes they are, I am already sending the windows credentials for the user ("domain", "username" and "password" credentials). Do you mean to send the data source credentials also (username: sa, password: ****)? In that case how do you do that?

Comment: But as I wrote, if I upload a report through Visual studio, there is no prompting for credentials happening, no matter where I access the report from, it's predefined.